# Restrict Microsoft Graph Service Account / Client Credentials

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm developing an application on Microsoft Graph that runs as a daemon, and needs access to many accounts. As a result, I'm using a service account, also known as client credentials (using [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) method).

I can request the proper scope (`calendars.readwrite`) however as far as I can see, I cannot restrict to which calendars I have access. In my case, I only need access to the meetingroom calendars, and I'm afraid that organisations will not allow my application if I can also read and write from/to the CEO's calendar.

Is there any way (either while creating the app, or during/after giving admin consent) to restrict my app to only a subset of calendars? Or should I approach this problem differently and (e.g.) not use a service account in the first place?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273451/graph-authentication-through-client-credentials-flow-will-my-app-have-access-t